# flexible array member in a nested struct

Tags: c, struct, flexible-array-member

Is it valid C code to have flexible array members inside nested structs? So is my sample code below guarenteed to work as expected with a sane compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct d {
    char c;
    int ns[];
};

struct c {
    struct d d;
};

struct b {
    struct c c;
};

struct a {
    int n;
    struct b b;
};

int main() {
    const int n = 10;
    struct a *pa = malloc(sizeof(*pa) + n * sizeof(pa->b.c.d.ns[0]));
    pa->n = n;
    pa->b.c.d.c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        pa->b.c.d.ns[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", pa->b.c.d.ns[i] + pa->b.c.d.c);
    }
    free(pa);
}
```

Comment: Yes. You can even let ns just be an int* and dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: In addition to Ulfalizer's answer, it's probably worth mentioning that flexible array members have an indeterminate size. For the `sizeof` operator's sake, flexible array members are not counted in the size of the type themselves, though such members may obviously still affect padding (e.g. you wouldn't start an array of `double` objects at memory address `0xDEADBEEF` due to alignment constraints).

Comment: (continued) Given the lack of size of flexible array members and `struct foo { struct d d; int n; };`, suppose you made `d.ns` an array of 200 items. `n` has a static offset, so `d.ns[0]` might also be `n`. This complication is why nesting a structure possessing a flexible array member is forbidden.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Good points. I assumed the OP understood that the FAM needed to be at the end, but it's worth mentioning. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not valid per the standard. I'm not sure how reliable it is in practice.

C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), §6.7.2.1.3 says the following (emphasis mine):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), *except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array.*

Later on, §6.7.2.1.18 clarifies that the above is referring to flexible array members (FAMs):

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*.

From some quick experimentation, GCC and Clang both add the trailing padding required to align the FAM properly even when the `struct` is nested, and only warn about structures with FAMs being members of other structures or arrays if `-Wpedantic` is passed, so take that as a sign that it'll probably work if you will :). It feels a bit hackish though.

Note that it probably wouldn't make sense to have the FAM anywhere but at the end. If you do

```
struct e {
    struct d d;
    int n;
} e;
```

, then `e.d.ns[0]` and `e.n` are likely to overlap in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
struct d {
    char c;
    int ns[];
};

struct a {
    int n;
    int d_fam[];
};

int main() {
    const int n = 10;
    struct a *pa = malloc(offsetof (struct a, d_fam) + offsetof (stuct d, ns) + n * sizeof(int));
    struct d *pd = pa + (uintptr_t) offsetof (struct a, d_fam);
    pa->n = n;
    pd->c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        pd->ns[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf ("%d\n", pd->ns[i] + pd->c);
    }
    free(pa);
}
```